# Grobner bases of a determinantal ideal

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, groebner-basis

I've been studying algebraic geometry recently and there is a problem I'm struggling with:

Suppose $A$ is a $m\times n$ complex matrix of rank $\leq r$, this is equivalent to all its $(r+1)\times (r+1)$ minors vanish. Hence the determinants of these minors define a projective variety. Then consider its ideal. I wonder whether these minors form a reduced Grobner basis for such $A$.

Theorem 1 in [this paper](http://www.ricam.oeaw.ac.at/Groebner-Bases-Bibliography/gbbib_files/publication_1095.pdf) seems to prove this but for generic matrices.

What does "generic" mean in this context? Can we just say the minors form a reduced Grobner basis for any complex matrix with rank $\leq r$?

Comment: *Generic matrix* is a matrix whose entries are indeterminates. And yes, all the minors of given size form a reduced Grobner basis for the ideal they generate.

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick reply. Just to be sure, when you say indeterminates, do you mean the entries are treated as free variable?

Comment: Exactly. ${}{}{}$